# directory moved automatically after reboot ubuntu 22.04

Tags: reboot, system, paths

I'm a newbie here and I wondered why my files moved from ~/Desktop to ~/ after I rebooted my notebook from bash. I downloaded the community version of intellijidea and unzipped it on the desktop (I donno if there is a proper path to place programs yet). I ran it and then I rebooted. Suddenly I saw that my files moved. Just why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't happen. What changes have you made to your system? How did you "downloaded and placed on the `~/Desktop`"? How did you reboot your sysrem? Where do your files reside? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.